# Google Cloud DNS - Subdomains wildcard not working

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, dns-zone, google-cloud-dns

I got one domain example.com on app engine.
All subdomains a.example.com, b.example.com, c.example.com... have to point on example.com.

I'm configuring everything from Cloud DNS of Google Cloud, my configuration is like that:

```
*.example.com.  CNAME   300 ghs.googlehosted.com.
example.com.    AAAA    300 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::xx
example.com.    AAAA    300 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::xx
example.com.    AAAA    300 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::xx
example.com.    AAAA    300 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::xx
example.com.    A       300 xxx.xxx.xx.xx
example.com.    A       300 xxx.xxx.xx.xx
example.com.    A       300 xxx.xxx.xx.xx
example.com.    A       300 xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Already tried to do something like

```
*.example.com.  CNAME   300 example.com.
```

But not working.

If I use DIG to check my DNS, I got correct answer

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
a.example.com.          300     IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
ghs.googlehosted.com.   218     IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

When I go on a.example.com from my browser, i got ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: Are you using Google Managed SSL Certificates? If yes, wildcards are not supported. Edit your question and show your App Engine configuration files.

Comment: Yes, I'm using google managed SSL Certificates. This configuration with app engine already working on another domain, but I'm using a custom SSL certificate and not using Google Cloud DNS. What I've done is basicallly copy/paste DNS configuration. Do you think problem is the Google SSL certificate? In that case, a.example.com over HTTP  (not HTTPS), should be reachable or not? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As @John Hanley mentioned, Google Managed SSL Certificate does not support wildcard (*.example.com).

I've just created a new certificate with Letsencrypt and wildcard seems working.

Comment: GCP support wildcard hostname certificates now https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Google Managed SSL Certificates then wild cards will not be supported.
You can use wildcards to map subdomains at any level, starting at third-level
subdomains.

Kindly refer to the below link for:

Mapping custom Domains :
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards

Securing Custom Domains with SSL :
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Mhaske, welcome to the community!  For the sake of completeness, it's often desirable that the answers are self-contained, meaning that instead of just linking to documentation, the important parts should be copied into the answer.